# JADE templating engine does not render ng-include

Tags: angularjs, partial-views, pug

I have the following snippet in my index.jade

```
...
div(ng-include='ng-include', src='contentInclude')
...
```

I have contentInclude.jade in the same directory as index.jade but when I access index.jade, contentInclude.jade is not being rendeered.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.
Melroy

Answer (score 2):

I used:

```
div(ng-include="'contentInclude.jade'")
```

And it works like a charm!

Comment: Instead of escaping single quotes, wouldn't double quotes around the attribute value also work? `div(ng-include="'contentInclude.jade'")`

Answer (score 1):

When use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) as an element, you can do

```
ng-include(src='\'contentInclude.jade\'')
```

as attribute:

```
div(ng-include='\'contentInclude.jade\'')
```